# Accessibility to the Privacy tab using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to access the Privacy - > Accessibility tab using Applescript. Can anyone help me? I need to output a list of all programs in the terminal.

I think, but not correctly

osascript -e 'tell application "System Preferences" set securityPane to pane id "com.apple.preference.security" to get the name of every Privacy_Accessibility'

[image]

Comment: Tested in **macOS Catalina** --- With **System Preferences** opened to what you show in the image, then in **Terminal** this will output the _names_: `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get the value of static text 1 of UI element 1 of rows of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"'`

Comment: The answer is unclear to me. What do I need to enter to see the information about which application names are contained in Privacy--> Accessibility

Comment: Without binding to the window

Comment: RE: "The answer is unclear to me. What do I need to enter to see the information about which application names are contained in Privacy--> Accessibility" --  If you want to get the _name_ of each _application_ that is listed under **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** then open **System Preferences** to that _pane_ and select **Accessibility** and then in **Terminal** run the _command_ from my first comment and it will output the _names_. --- RE: "Without binding to the window" -- I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: To get to the _Accessibility_ section under _Security & Privacy_, you can: **`tell application id "com.apple.systempreferences" to reveal the anchor named "Privacy_Accessibility" in pane id "com.apple.preference.security"`** or you can invoke its URI scheme: **`open location "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Accessibility"`**

Comment: I need to display a list in the terminal, without using the GUI. Example: osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get the name of every login item'                                to get the name of each element in a row terminal .

Comment: RE: "I need to display a list in the terminal, without using the GUI. Example: osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get the name of every login item' to get the name of each element in a row terminal ." -- 
There is no direct query such as that for what you are asking. If you want the _name_ of each _application_ that is listed under **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** then you'll need to do as presented in my answer below.

Comment: Yes I need it
But I can't use a separate script, run via osascript -e. Within the framework of Terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

It was also tested used as a *shell script* with a `#!/usr/bin/osascript` *shebang*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # Set the value of targetRow to the name of the target row as shown  
--  # in Privacy tab of Security & Privacy pane in System Preferences.

set targetRow to "Accessibility"


--  # Do not modify the code below unless necessary.

property |System Preferences| : name of ¬
    application id "com.apple.systempreferences"


--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application id "com.apple.systempreferences" then
    try
        tell application id "com.apple.systempreferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall '" & |System Preferences| & "'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of ¬
    application id "com.apple.systempreferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open System Preferences to the Security & Privacy pane.

tell application id "com.apple.systempreferences"
    run -- # Used as a workaround to an issue in Big Sur.
    delay 0.1
    reveal anchor "Privacy_Accessibility" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.security"
end tell

--  # Use System Events to achieve the goal.

tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
    run -- # Used as a workaround to an issue in Big Sur.
    delay 0.2
    tell window 1 of application process |System Preferences|
        
        --  # Wait for target pane to be available.
        
        my waitForUIelement(row -1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1)
        
        --  # Ascertain the target row to select.
        
        set rowTargetRow to first item of ¬
            (rows of table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 ¬
                whose value of static text 1 of UI element 1 is targetRow)
        
        --  # Select the target row.
        
        select rowTargetRow
        
        --  # Wait for target UI element to be available.
        
        my waitForUIelement(button 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1)
        
        --  # Get the names of the applications.
        
        set appNames to the value of ¬
            static text 1 of UI element 1 of ¬
            rows of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
        
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.02

quit application id "com.apple.systempreferences"

--  # Output the names of the applications.

return appNames


--  ## Handler ##

on waitForUIelement(uiElement)
    tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
        tell window 1 of application process ¬
            |System Preferences|
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists uiElement
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 40 then return
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end waitForUIelement
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>